# How to create an App folder accessible also by others Apps using SAF in latest Android version without disrupt user experience

Tags: android, storage-access-framework, android-storage, android-11

Scenario an App create documents and has to store and open them.
Before SAF creating a *MyAppDocument* folder, where the App can store and open every file, was a smooth operation,
now with SAF if I use the intent with `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` in order to get access to the storage place where this folder must be created:

1- Appears the directory access picker dialog

2- If picker is positioned on main storage path(both internal or external sd card) and I target latest Android API level 30, the path cannot be selected and appears also an additional intimidating privacy warning that invite user to create a new folder or select another path to avoid privacy problems as shown in the picture (absurd considering that is supposes to be an user space not some system root directory)

[image]

The user can still follow the suggestion to choose a different path or create another folder then choose such path, but this is **horrible** for user experience, and many users will uninstall the app bothered or scared.

Is there another way to create a folder for the App that can be easily accessible by the user file manager\other apps(so the user can easily copy, open and move and manage files created inside it) without asking so many manual actions to the user?

Comment: "without asking so many manual actions to the user?" -- the "so many manual actions" is no different than the experience on a desktop OS, other than the lack of a tree widget. "File open", "file save as", and "choose directory" dialogs are common approaches with desktop apps (and, by extension, with Web apps that use local files).

Comment: @CommonsWare Not even on desktop are required so many steps to use an app after the installation, in every desktop there is an accessible user space where App works without needs of additional special permissions, now the supposed user space has been limited in a similar way of a root access, and the experience on a phone App must be smoother than one on a desktop PC

Comment: CREATE NEW FOLDER is not intimidating. And you can let the user create a nice folder for your app wich is reachable for other apps too using saf.

Comment: "in every desktop there is an accessible user space where App works without needs of additional special permissions" -- primarily, in Android, those are `getFilesDir()`, `getCacheDir()`, `getExternalFilesDir()`, `getExternalCacheDir()`, and related methods on `Context`. Secondarily, those are a few particular collections in `MediaStore`. "and the experience on a phone App must be smoother than one on a desktop PC" -- I strongly disagree.

Comment: @CommonsWare In desktop an installed App can create folders and read and write files in user path without all such mess, in Android no more, and I have to ask storage permission, folder permission, the user has to create another folder "manually" (unless you have a different solution) and then He must click allow. This is objectively a lot worse user experience than desktop, not same experience.

Comment: "In desktop an installed App can create folders and read and write files in user path without all such mess" -- not in arbitrary locations. Most of a hard drive is inaccessible to a desktop program, for security reasons. Many newer solutions (e.g., snaps and AppImage on Linux) provide very little filesystem access by default, routing everything through the sorts of dialogs that you dislike, for better privacy and security. I do not dispute that the SAF UI could be better.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have said "user space" not arbitrary locations in whole storage memory, the folder that I'm trying to access is user space as linux `/home/` directory or windows user folder not some root space. Before SAF the separation was desktop comparable with some area of storage memory accessible only with rooted access and the user space freely accessible, now all the user space is treated as some root space with needs of special permissions for everything, creating an huge mess (even in the external sd). Don't try to deny reality it's no way near comparable.

Comment: "I'm trying to access is user space as linux /home/ directory or windows user folder not some root space" -- modern Linux packaging options (snaps, AppImage, etc.) do not allow access to `~`. The industry is trending towards better security, as because with each passing year the trash fire of OS security becomes more obvious and claims more victims. Could the SAF UI be better? Yes.

Comment: @CommonsWare You continue to compare different things as they are comparable when they aren't. I'm already trying to access this with SAF not with direct file system access, in linux even such for you "modern" package manager as Snappy allow to access home path just in a different way, here you cannot at all and you have to go for a specific subfolder, and it's no the industry that is "trending" it's some specific company for specific reasons that is adopting this approach absurdly restrictive.and seems evident that real reason is unified storage model for pushing cloud services

Comment: also creating directly a public folder in user space storage with read and write access in the created folder itself (and not even the others files or folders in it) is a very basic kind of action and doesn't compromise any privacy, but seems you are forced to route to interactive permission dialog mess anyway because you have to get the access token with SAF in the folder where you want to create it regardless,

Answer (score 0):

I agree, SAF as implemented does not work for solutions where a real file path is needed, and for a user to copy files into and out of with other apps, or even windows explorer.  The concept of copying files out with SAF into your sandbox location is also not good, as when dealing with 1000s of files, or even a small amount of very large files/duplicates is basically a silly solution.  All modern  OS(s) have a public location and a private location.  If I use the document tree/intent and have the user create read/write access to the directory, yet still not giving me full access is short sighted for many app developers, as a multi-platform solution needs full paths to the files my app creates or other apps that put the files into this directory they created JUST FOR MY APP, which was CREATED THROUGH my app.